# Android Development: How to get no pop up keyboard with an EditText

Tags: android

I am a beginner with android development, and I was wondering if it is possible to make it so that when the user touches the EditText, no keyboard pops up. I want this because I have created buttons that correspond to numbers, so when they touch the button, a 1 will appear in the edittext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a spinner (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) with all your numbers loaded from an array resource.

Any way, if you don't want to edit your EditText you could set editable to false on the XML layout.

```
android:editable="false"
```